# I want to connect Google Sheets that stores answers from Google Form with my PHPMyAdmin database

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to build a WordPress site for my thesis, I am using Xampp and PHPMyAdmin to store my database. The task I want to achieve is to exctract the answers from Google Sheets dynamically and store them in a table on my database so I can use them in my Wordpress site in order to change background colors of icons depending on the answers (Yes=green, No=Red).

So im trying to find a Wordpress plugin (open-source) or any other way, that can store the google sheet answers in my database, and then retrieve the values to solve my task.I have tried Google App Script but it doesnt worked. Also my wordpress site is local (for now).

Comment: There are several ways to connect WordPress and Google Sheets including WordPress Plugins and Google Sheets Add-Ins. So far as app script is concerned, there is the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment! Do you have any Wordpress-plugins or Google Sheets Add-Ins you could suggest me? I want the whole proccess to be automated every time someone sumbits a Google Form answer (that stores the answers in the Google Sheets)

Comment: `Do you have any Wordpress-plugins or Google Sheets Add-Ins you could suggest me?` I'm sorry but requests for recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow and WordPress.StackExchange.